# How to create group of coordinates and check if a coordinate is within the group?

Tags: coordinates, geotools

I am looking for a way to relate two or more types of open data from the Valencia Open data portal. This portal offer data like a [traffic jam](http://apigobiernoabiertortod.valencia.es/apirtod/rest/collections.json), noise, and [air pollution](http://gobiernoabierto.valencia.es/en/dataset/?id=estaciones-automaticas-atmosfericas). All these data have coordinates based on the locality of real sensors. So, I am using [GeoTools](https://geotools.org/) which is a java library, to work with these data.
Now I want to create some polygon groups inside Valencia city in order to say if some coordinates are close to each other. For example, I imagine that if a coordinate XY and XY' are in the same group, it is likely that they are close to each other.

How can I create these groups? I am searching [here](https://www.mbi-geodata.com/en/mbi-supplier-manufacturer-worldwide-geodata/western-europe/spain-maps/) but I don't have too many ideas on how to proceed on this.

For example, let's say I have 5 points and I want to create sets with points that are close to each other in at least 3 meters. My result would be 2 sets like below:

```
point A: 44, 33
point B: 44, 34
point C: 45, 34
point D: 54, 53
point E: 55, 55

set 1: points {A, B, C}
set 2: points {D, E}
```

Comment: what do you mean by close to each other? do you want the closest x points, or all points within 5m? 50m? 10km?

Comment: I wrote an example. basically, it is your second option. all the points within 5 meters.

Comment: you could create a polygon around a point by buffering.